# Remove all children of children in Pixi Application

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to remove all children of childen in a pixi application however some sprite items still remain and fail after a tween..  The following is located in a class titled appEntry.

```
create(){
    this.renderer = new Renderer({ resolution: window.devicePixelRatio });
    this.renderer.backgroundColor = 0x260244;

    this.app = new Container(); 
    this.loader = new Loader(); 

    console.log('PIXI APP INIT!');

    document.getElementById('pixi-render').appendChild(this.renderer.view);
    console.log('RENDERER APPENDED:', this.renderer);
    console.log('PIXI APP APPENDED:', this.app);

    AnimationStore.subscribe(() => {
       this.renderer.render(this.app);
    });

    Store.subscribe(() => {
       const { color, coloron } = Store.getState().App;
    });

    const main = new Main();
    this.app.removeChild(this.loader);
    this.app.addChild(main); 
    this.renderer.start();
}

destroy(){
    this.app.destroy(true);
    this.app = null;

    this.renderer.view.destroy( true );
    this.renderer.view = null;

    while(this.app.children[0]) { 
    this.app.removeChild(this.app.children[0]); }

    this.renderer.destroy( true );
    this.renderer = null;
    console.log('PIXI APP APPENDED:', this.app);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the destroy method is incorrectly designed, and it's not clear why you don't have errors in browser at execution time: **this.app variable is** nullified earlier than removing all children from it **while(this.app.children[0])**

For the beginning, I would recommend change the methot next way:

```
destroy(){
    while(this.app.children[0]) { 
        this.app.removeChild(this.app.children[0]);
    }

    this.app.destroy(true);
    this.app = null;

    this.renderer.view.destroy( true );
    this.renderer.view = null;

    this.renderer.destroy( true );
    this.renderer = null;
    console.log('PIXI APP APPENDED:', this.app);
}
```

Also, make sure your errors are not connected to the fact that tweens are still active, but their tween-targets are already nullified/removed/destroyed. If it's  the case, then in addition to removing visual objects you need to stop/destroy all tweens.